Special Circle Packing problem, what is the least number of circles that can be fitted inside another circle?
Background & Motivation:
It is a brand new problem I came up with while studying Apollonian gaskets and circle packing, which requires more brain power than I have. It is currently at the beginning stage of study. I hope this problem gets noticed by more mathematicians and I hope for a solution. The first challenge is to identify the value of $L (L<0.5)$ for which there is more than one solution for $i$. I am no mathematician, so my formulation of the problem may lack the appearance please do provide suggestions.
Context & Definitions:
$C_M$ = The largest circle in the system of circles i.e.$C_M$={$C_1,C_2,C_3, ..., C_n$}
$A_M$ = Area of the circle $C_M$ and
$C_i$ = The circles to be fitted inside the circle $C_M$ i.e. $C_i∈C_M$
$A_i$ = Area of the circle $C_i$= $L^i∗A_M$ and $A_1>A_2>A_3>...>A_n$.
$i$ = numerical identifying entity; $i∈N$
$L$ = The ratio of the area of $C_M$ to the area of the largest circle $C_1 (i=1)$ we consider fitting inside the circle $C_M = A_M/A_1$.  And $L<0.5$.
PROBLEM STATEMENT:
What is the least number of circles $C_i$
that can be fitted inside a circle $C_M$
under the following conditions i.e. solve for the least value of i
for a certain value of $L (L<0.5)$:

The circles $C_i$
cannot share a common area.($C_i ∩ C_{i+1}=∅
 $)

The system must contain the maximum number of circles $C_i$
of the same area as possible i.e. we have to fit more than one of any circle $C_i$ provided that there is enough space left to do it. We can't start fitting circle $C_{i+1}$ unless the maximum possible number of circles $C_i$ have been fitted inside $C_M$.


A representation of the problem is attached to the post.See a sample image here


Your question  "how many are they..." has an computational geometry counterpart : "how (in an algorithmical way) can the radii of the disks been chosen and the disks placed ?". 2) I don't understand why you go backwards ($i-1$ index instead of $i+1$).


@JeanMarie 1) Yes, the radius is chosen based on the area condition, i.e. solely dependent on what we consider the value for L and placing the circles in a specific way fulfilling the conditions provided in the statement, 2) it was a typo, thanks for pointing it out.
